# Confused on dictionary input example in Python Crash Course

Tags: python, dictionary, input

I am working my way through Python Crash Course, and in Chapter 8 the author gives the following code as an example for filling a dictionary with user input.  I am confused in the step where he stores the responses into the dictionary, as to my eye it looks as though he is only saving one piece of , "response" which is immutable data to the "responses" dictionary under the key "name".  I am missing how both the name input and response input are put into the dictionary.

It seems to make no sense to me, but that is what I have loved about this journey so far, finding sense in seeming nonsense.  Thank you for helping demystify this world for me.

```
responses = {}

# Set a flag to indicate that polling is active.
polling_active = True

while polling_active:
    #Prompt for the person's name and response.
    name = input("\nWhat is your name? ")
    response = input("Which mountain would you like to climb someday? ")

    #Store the response in the dictionary:
    responses[name] = response

    #Find out if anyone else is going to take the poll.
    repeat = input("Would you like to let another person respond? (yes/no) ")
    if repeat == 'no':
        polling_active = False

#Polling is complete.  Show the results.
print("\n--- Poll Results ---")
for name, response in responses.items():
    print(name + " would like to climb " + response + ".")
```

Comment: What happens when you run it? Does it behave the way you think it does?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking? *As you say in the question*, `responses[name] = response` stores the `response` by the key `name` - i.e. both are in the dict afterwards.

Comment: Yes, it runs perfectly.  I was confused with assigning both key and value in the same time in the one line.  Just a beginner oversight.

Comment: If the course you're taking is offering that code as "the way it should be done" then I suggest you look for another course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing with dictionaries is that you can change the value of the key like this: `dictionary[key] = value`. If the key doesn't exist it will simply create a new key. You don't need any function like `append` which is used for lists. The line where you wrote `responses[name] = response` works because it stays in a while loop. After the loop runs again it asks another input and replaces the old `name` with a new `name` and old `response` with a new `response`. In conclusion, name and response is added every time the loop runs if the name is not already in the dictionary. If the name is there then it will simply change its value `response` if that is different from the old one.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does.  I have been mixing up assigning variables, list components and dictionary key/values, but your explanation helped it click.  Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In the most basic explanation, dictionaries associates an arbitrary value at an arbitrary key. So, what the author is actually doing is associating the user's response with their name. The author does this by using the name as a key and the response as a value. Using dictionaries like this is fairly common.

If you want to retrieve a value in the array, you must know it key. However, you can retrieve all key and value pairs with `dictionary.items()`. This way, the author can get those two associated pieces of data (the name and the response).

Comment: That makes sense.  I wasn't understanding that both the key and value were being assigned at the same time.  Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`name` and `response` are variables names that are filled with the inputted data, let's say `'John'` and `'Kalimanjaro'`.

Now, `'John'` and `'Kalimanjaro'` are indeed immutable, but that doesn't mean you can't replace the values stored in `name` and `response` in the next loop. You can assign a new value, maybe also immutable, to `name` if you want.

One possible source of confusion could be that you started learning dictionaries using statements like `responses['John'] = 'Kalimanjaro'`, where both key and value were strings. Now you are doing `responses[name] = response` (no quotes around `name` and `response`). So you create a key called whatever was stored in `name` and a value with whatever was stored in `response`.

If in the next iteration the value of `name` is replaced by, let's say `'Maria'` and `response` becomes `'Andes'`, the new `responses[name] = response` will be equivalent to `responses['Maria'] = 'Andes'`.

Comment: That makes sense and I believe one source of confusion for me.  Another confusion is that if I am replacing the key and value by running each loop, how is it being permanently stored in the dictionary?  It seems like it is adding keys and values to dictionary rather than replacing them.

Comment: Because each time, name is holding a different string. In my example, in the first loop it will do `responses['John'] = ...`, but in the second `responses['Maria'] = ...`.

Comment: Let me propose you something: in your code, right after `responses[name] = response`, add another line `print(f"name = {name},  response = {response},  responses = {responses}")`, so you see how the dictionary populates in each iteration.

Comment: That is a good tip.  Thanks again.